# How to get the value of OID in Python using PySnmp

Tags: python, python-3.x, snmp, pysnmp

Using `snmpwalk` I can get this from my device:

```
OID=.1.3.6.1.4.1.5296.1.9.1.1.1.7.115.101.99.99.97.57.27.1.41
Type=OctetString
Value=secca99
```

I tried this program in Python to get the value field from above OID:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from pysnmp.hlapi import *
import sys

def walk(host, oid):

    for (errorIndication,
         errorStatus,
         errorIndex,
         varBinds) in nextCmd(SnmpEngine(),
                              CommunityData('public'),
                              UdpTransportTarget((host, 161)),
                              ContextData(),
                              ObjectType(ObjectIdentity(oid))):

        if errorIndication:
            print(errorIndication, file=sys.stderr)
            break

        elif errorStatus:
            print('%s at %s' % (errorStatus.prettyPrint(),
                                errorIndex and varBinds[int(errorIndex) - 1][0] or '?'), file=sys.stderr)
            break

        else:
            for varBind in varBinds:
                print(varBind)


walk('10.78.163.39',
     '.1.3.6.1.4.1.5296.1.9.1.1.1.7.115.101.99.99.97.57.27.1.41')
```

**Output** i get:

When i run the program, it shows a long list of OID's (don't know why even I am giving the leaf level OID as input in program) with values. STRANGE.

**What is tried**

`lexicographicMode=True` in the `nextCmd` but it doesn't show anything than.

**What i wish**

I want to give a list of OID in my program and wants their values(value is a key you can see in first line), that's it.

**Request**

Please help me in python program to do so using pysnmp.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want OIDs, use [mibLookup=False](http://snmplabs.com/pysnmp/docs/hlapi/asyncore/sync/manager/cmdgen/nextcmd.html#getnext-command) parameter. If you want just the branch of the MIB, use `lexicographicMode=False`, but make sure to specify non-leaf OID because in that case you will get nothing in return.

Here's your script with the suggested changes:

```
from pysnmp.hlapi import *
import sys

def walk(host, oid):

    for (errorIndication,
         errorStatus,
         errorIndex,
         varBinds) in nextCmd(SnmpEngine(),
                              CommunityData('public'),
                              UdpTransportTarget((host, 161)),
                              ContextData(),
                              ObjectType(ObjectIdentity(oid)),
                              lookupMib=False,
                              lexicographicMode=False):

        if errorIndication:
            print(errorIndication, file=sys.stderr)
            break

        elif errorStatus:
            print('%s at %s' % (errorStatus.prettyPrint(),
                                errorIndex and varBinds[int(errorIndex) - 1][0] or '?'), file=sys.stderr)
            break

        else:
            for varBind in varBinds:
                 print('%s = %s' % varBind)

walk('demo.snmplabs.com', '1.3.6.1.2.1.1.9.1.2')
```

You should be able to cut&paste it, it's running against public SNMP simulator at [demo.snmplabs.com](http://demo.snmplabs.com).

Comment: Thanks @llya, similarly i have created 2 more programs, grt. usiing wireshark i can see a request-id goes on when i run this program, can i get the request id number using python program similarly, when i run this program i basically give community:public and version v2c, but in get-response i get request-id, this is what is need to fetch. Please help me out how to do it. Here is the image of snmp response in wireshark. https://i.imgur.com/aH5gO4B.png