# How to get the request-id from snmp response

Tags: django, snmp, pysnmp

Using wireshark i can see a request-id goes on when i run this program ([How to get the value of OID in Python using PySnmp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49137695/how-to-get-the-value-of-oid-in-python-using-pysnmp)), can i get the request-id number using python program similarly, when i run this program i basically give community:public and version v2c, but in get-response i get request-id, this is what is need to fetch. Please help me out how to do it. Here is the image of snmp response in wireshark.

[image]

Comment: So, did you get your answer?

Answer (score 3):

Well, `request-id` is something very private to the SNMP mechanics. But you still can get it if you want.

With pysnmp, you can use the built-in hooks to have it calling back your function and passing it the internal data belonging to SNMP engine processing the request.

```
...

# put this in your script's initialization section

context = {}

def request_observer(snmpEngine, execpoint, variables, context):
    pdu = variables['pdu']
    request_id = pdu['request-id']
    # this is just a way to pass fetched data from the callback out
    context['request-id'] = request_id

snmpEngine.observer.registerObserver(
    request_observer,
    'rfc3412.receiveMessage:request',
     cbCtx=context
)

...
```

Now, once you get SNMP message the normal way, `request-id` for its `PDU` should be stored in `context['request-id']`. You can get practically everything about underlying SNMP data structures that way.

Comment: Excellent answer, one comment: if one is interested in the `request-id` of the SNMP SET executed by pysnmp the `rfc3412.receiveMessage:response` should be "observed". This way the `reuqest-id` can be acquired from the SET RESPONSE message. Based on the screenshot the OP wants the same, get the `request-id` from the response PDU.